# Exception in ShowDialog from different Window

Tags: wpf

I have a custom Window I want to show, when an unhandled exception occurs. Something like this:

```
private void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        e.Handled = true; // If e.Handled == false or error dialog will not show.
        string errorMassage = ExceptionFormatter.FormatException(e.Exception)
        var window = new FatalErrorWindow(errorMassage );
        window.ShowDialog();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(errorMassage, "Program error", MessageBoxButton.OK);            
    }
    Application.Current.Shutdown(-1);
}
```

In some situations the ShowDialog itself throws an exception, so I added a try/catch for that, and discovered that when ShowDialog is called, it seems as if .NET performs a full UpdateLayout cycle *for a different window* (the main window presumably?).

Now the problem is that if that cycle throws an exception during the Measure/Arrange phase, that is basically not possible to handle gracefully. Any attempt to show a pretty dialog will run into the same exception.

*Does anyone have a suggestion how to fix/get around this?*¨

**EDIT:** *(In response to comment)*

My concern is that I cannot try/catch anything to prevent this. ANY UI element - that being my own, a 3rd party or even a .NET element - in a completely unrelated part of the application, could throw a NullReferenceException in a Measure/Arrange method, and it is essentially uncatchable.

Below is a stacktrace which illustrates the problem.

> at 3rdPartyVendor.UI.Xaml.Grid.GridDataRow.UpdateFixedRowState()
>   at
>   3rdPartyVendor.UI.Xaml.Grid.RowGenerator.EnsureRows(VisibleLinesCollection
>   visibleRows)    at
>   3rdPartyVendor.UI.Xaml.Grid.VisualContainer.EnsureItems(Boolean
>   ensureColumns)    at
>   3rdPartyVendor.UI.Xaml.Grid.VisualContainer.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint)    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element,
>   Size constraint) in f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\MS\Internal\Helper.cs:line
>   547    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Primitives\ScrollContentPresenter.cs:line
>   432    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1431
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead,
>   Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1286
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead,
>   Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1250
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 701    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
>   in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\ScrollViewer.cs:line
>   1220    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Border.cs:line 245
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1431
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead,
>   Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1286
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead,
>   Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1250
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 701    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Control.cs:line 711
>   at 3rdPartyVendor.UI.Xaml.Grid.SfDataGrid.MeasureOverride(Size
>   availableSize)    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1431
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead,
>   Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1286
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead,
>   Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1250
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 701    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element,
>   Size constraint) in f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\MS\Internal\Helper.cs:line
>   547    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\ContentPresenter.cs:line
>   495    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Control.cs:line 711
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   XXXXXX.Common.Controls.CachingPanel.MeasureOverride(Size
>   availableSize) in
>   F:\git\XXXXXXX\Source\XXXXXX.Common\Controls\CachingPanel.cs:line 84
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 441    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Border.cs:line 245
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Control.cs:line 711
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element,
>   Size constraint) in f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\MS\Internal\Helper.cs:line
>   547    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\ContentPresenter.cs:line
>   495    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 441    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1431
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead,
>   Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1286
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead,
>   Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1250
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 701    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element,
>   Size constraint) in f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\MS\Internal\Helper.cs:line
>   547    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\ContentPresenter.cs:line
>   495    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 441    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Control.cs:line 711
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Control.cs:line 711
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element,
>   Size constraint) in f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\MS\Internal\Helper.cs:line
>   547    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\ContentPresenter.cs:line
>   495    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Border.cs:line 245
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1431
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead,
>   Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1286
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead,
>   Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1250
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 701    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 441    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Control.cs:line 711
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element,
>   Size constraint) in f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\MS\Internal\Helper.cs:line
>   547    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\ContentPresenter.cs:line
>   495    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Control.cs:line 711
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   XXXXXX.Common.Controls.CachingPanel.MeasureOverride(Size
>   availableSize) in
>   F:\git\XXXXXXX\Source\XXXXXX.Common\Controls\CachingPanel.cs:line 84
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1431
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead,
>   Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1286
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead,
>   Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1250
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 701    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element,
>   Size constraint) in f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\MS\Internal\Helper.cs:line
>   547    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\ContentPresenter.cs:line
>   495    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Control.cs:line 711
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   XXXXXX.Common.Controls.CachingPanel.MeasureOverride(Size
>   availableSize) in
>   F:\git\XXXXXXX\Source\XXXXXX.Common\Controls\CachingPanel.cs:line 84
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 441    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Border.cs:line 245
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Control.cs:line 711
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 441    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1431
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead,
>   Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1286
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead,
>   Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 1250
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Grid.cs:line 701    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element,
>   Size constraint) in f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\MS\Internal\Helper.cs:line
>   547    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\ContentPresenter.cs:line
>   495    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Documents\AdornerDecorator.cs:line
>   129    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Controls\Border.cs:line 245
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4402
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverrideHelper(Size constraint) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Window.cs:line 3497    at
>   System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Window.cs:line 1881    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\FrameworkElement.cs:line 4323
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()    **at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()**    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
>   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value)
>   **at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisual() in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Window.cs:line 2967**    at
>   System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisualAndUpdateSTC() in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Window.cs:line 2978    at
>   System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double requestedTop, Double
>   requestedLeft, Double requestedWidth, Double requestedHeight) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Window.cs:line 2942    at
>   System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean duringShow) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Window.cs:line 2679    at
>   System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowDuringShow() in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Window.cs:line 2532    at
>   System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindowDuringShow() in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Window.cs:line 5643    at
>   System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox) in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Window.cs:line 5743    at
>   System.Windows.Window.Show() in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Window.cs:line 214    **at
>   System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog() in
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\Framework\System\Windows\Window.cs:line 516**    at
>   XXXXXX.Common.Controls.MultiButtonDialog.ShowOK(Object content, String
>   title) in
>   F:\git\XXXXXXX\Source\XXXXXX.Common\Dialogs\MultiButtonDialog.xaml.cs:line
>   55    at
>   XXXXXX.Wpf.VelocityErrorHandler.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.b__0()
>   in F:\git\XXXXXXX\Source\XXXXXX.Wpf\VelocityFatalErrorHandler.cs:line
>   216    at XXXXXX.Wpf.WpfDispatcher.Invoke(Action action) in
>   F:\git\XXXXXXX\Source\XXXXXX.Wpf\WpfDispatcher.cs:line 32    at
>   DFDS.Freight.Common.Core.DispatchContext.Invoke(Action action) in
>   F:\git\XXXXXXX\Source\DFDS.Freight.Common.Portable\Core\IDispatchContext.cs:line
>   30    at
>   XXXXXX.Wpf.VelocityErrorHandler.HandleFatalException(Exception
>   exception) in
>   F:\git\XXXXXXX\Source\XXXXXX.Wpf\VelocityFatalErrorHandler.cs:line 206
>   at XXXXXX.Wpf.VelocityErrorHandler.HandleAnyException(Exception
>   exception, Boolean isUnhandledTaskException) in
>   F:\git\XXXXXXX\Source\XXXXXX.Wpf\VelocityFatalErrorHandler.cs:line 113
>   at XXXXXX.Wpf.VelocityErrorHandler.HandleUnhandledException(Exception
>   exception, Boolean isUnhandledTaskException) in
>   F:\git\XXXXXXX\Source\XXXXXX.Wpf\VelocityFatalErrorHandler.cs:line 29 
>   at
>   XXXXXX.Wpf.ApplicationInitializer.OnDispatcherUnhandledException(Object
>   sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) in
>   F:\git\XXXXXXX\Source\XXXXXX.Wpf\ApplicationInitializer.cs:line 605
>   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CatchException(Exception e)
>   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CatchExceptionStatic(Object
>   source, Exception e)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.CatchException(Object
>   source, Exception e, Delegate catchHandler)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler) 
>   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object
>   state)    at
>   MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object
>   obj)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question, I'm curious as to why?

Comment: Rather than working around the exceptions, maybe you should focus on why they are happening in the first place...

Comment: I get what you mean, but there are two reasons why that is not my focus. First, the exception happens in a 3rd party control. I can possible work around that, but it's not something I have directly control over. Second, even if I work around that exception, it will not help me the next time some piece of code (I cannot control) throws an exception during a layout pass. I concerns me that the UI component which is part of a totally different window, can cause my window to not show up.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your solution is in fact as good as it gets. You cannot guarantee a stable state when you end up in the `DispatcherUnhandledException` event handler. For instance, if your exceptions is thrown from deep inside WPF you will likely not be able to bind properties. Your error message dialog would be blank.

Below you find a fix for that particular issue.

```
private void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    var errorMassage = ExceptionFormatter.FormatException(e.Exception)

    try
    {            
        // When the WPF framework throws, our error dialog will have problem binding data.
        // In this case, we must revert to an oldschool message dialog in order to see
        // the actual error message!
        var isFrameworkError = ex.Source?.Equals("PresentationFramework") == true;
        if (isFrameworkError)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(errorMassage, "Program error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            var window = new FatalErrorWindow(errorMassage );
            window.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(errorMassage, "Program error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }

    Application.Current.Shutdown(-1);
}
```